# How to perform reload for captcha using SVG-captcha npm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, captcha

In my nodejs application,I am using svg-captcha,I have to reload the captcha to generate new without refreshing the page. is there any idea to perform using angular or any option is there in this npm

Answer (score 1):

```
**In HTML -**

    <a tabindex="-1" style="border-style: none;" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Refresh Image" ng-click="refreshCaptcha()">
    <img src="image/refresh.png" alt="Reload Image" height="25" width="25" onclick="this.blur()" align="bottom" border="0" /></a> 

**In Controller -** 

$scope.refreshCaptcha = function(){
        $http.get('SVG_Captcha_API').then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.captcha = response.data.data;
            $scope.captcha_text = response.data.text;
        });

    }
```